# How to convert while loop code to for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I want to convert the while loop below code to for loop.

```
i=1
while i<128:
    print(i , end=" ")   
    j=i
    while int(j/2)>0:
        print(int(j/2), end=" ")
        j=int(j/2)
    print()
    i=i*2
```

I'm facing a problem to increase "i" as "2*i"

Current Output

[image]

Comment: Are you asking the Python for-loop equivalent of this C for-loop - ```for(int i=1;i<32;i*=2)``` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post text as an image. Search engines can't index it and it will be inaccessible to people with certain disabilities, just to name two reasons out of many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by looping over the exponents of the numbers you're going to print, rather than looping on the numbers themselves:

```
for i in range(7):
    print(2**i, end=" ")
    for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
        print(2**j, end=" ")
    print()
```

This version of the code preserves the overall logic of your code, only changing the looping behavior. But it's not actually necessary to print out a value based on `i` separately from the values based on `j` in the inner loop, you could easily just have one version of that line, just by starting the inner loop on a slightly different value:

```
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(i, -1, -1):  # start at i, not i-1
        print(2**j, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: I already tried it and I know it works but the thing is I'm looking for a way where I can increase the "i" value by multiplying for example 2*i, 3*i.

Comment: `range` can't do a multiplicative sequence. So either use `2**i` and `3**i` after generating exponents, or write your own iterator type (e.g. with a generator function).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just increment the power of exponent:

```
max_power = 7
powers = []
for i in range(max_power):
   powers.insert(0, 2 ** i)
   print(*powers)
```

Answer (score 0):

A Python for loop runs through an iterator. It is not defined as (nor limited to) a striding mechanism.   To get a linear sequence, you would use the range() iterator that strides with a fixed increment.  For an exponential sequence, you would need an iterator function that progresses that way.

For example:

```
# exponential iterator
# this is a recursive example but it could be done differently

def iPower(base,stop,start=1):
    if start<stop:
       yield start
       yield from iPower(base,stop,start*base)
       
# converted to for loop
for i in iPower(2,128):
    print(i , end=" ")   
    j=i
    while int(j/2)>0:
        print(int(j/2), end=" ")
        j=int(j/2)
    print()
```

output:

```
1 
2 1 
4 2 1 
8 4 2 1 
16 8 4 2 1 
32 16 8 4 2 1 
64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

You could also make the iterator look like a C-style function using a lambda for the progression:

```
def cFor(start,stop,inc):
    while start<stop:
        yield start
        start = inc(start)
       
for i in cFor(1,128,lambda i:i*2):
    print(i , end=" ")   
    j=i
    while int(j/2)>0:
        print(int(j/2), end=" ")
        j=int(j/2)
    print()
```

A more generalized version of the cFor() function could allow you to convert both whiles to for loops by supporting use of either lambdas or constants for the stop condition and increment:

```
def cFor(start,stop,inc=1):
    while True:
        if callable(stop):
            if stop(start): return
        elif start >= stop: return
        yield start
        start = inc(start) if callable(inc) else (start+inc)
              
for i in cFor(1,128,lambda i:i*2):
    for j in cFor(i,lambda i:i<1,lambda i:i//2):
        print(j, end = " ")
    print()
```

If you're only looking for that specific kind of output with only the base and max exponent varying, a simple formulation could be this (change the '2' and '7' as needed):

```
for i in range(7): print(*(2**(i-j) for j in range(i+1)))
```